# FIRST set construction in compiler design

Tags: parsing, grammar

I have the following grammar.I have calculated the FIRST sets for all non terminals.But I am not sure if these are correct or not.

```
The grammar is as follows:

    E->TE'
    E'->+E|epsilon
    T->FT'
    T'->T|epsilon
    F->PF'
    F->*F'|epsilon
    P->(E)|a|b|epsilon

The FIRST sets for non terminals are as follows:

    FIRST(E)={(,a,b,*,+,epsilon}
    FIRST(E')={+,epsilon}
    FIRST(T)={(,a,b,*,epsilon}
    FIRST(T')={(,a,b,*,epsilon}
    FIRST(F)={(,a,b,*,epsilon}
    FIRST(F')={*,epsilon}
    FIRST(P)={(,a,b,epsilon}
```

Can anybody guide me if I am correct or not.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have calculated the wrong **First(F')** because as per your production

> F->PF'
>
> F->*F'|EPSILON

That is,

> F->PF'|F'|EPSILON

So in your above production **F'** is not given so we should consider **F'** as EPSILON that

> **F'->EPSILON**

So now the production will be

```
E->TE'
E'->+E|EPSILON
T->FT'
T'->T|EPSILON
F->PF'|*F'|EPSILON
F->EPSILON
P->(E)|a|b|EPSILON
```

Now applying the FIRST rule we get

> FIRST(E)=FIRST(T)-EPSILON U FIRST(E')
>
> ={(,a,b,* } U {+,EPSILON}
>
> ={ (,a,b,*,+,EPSILON }
>
> FIRST(E')={+,EPSILON}
>
> FIRST(T)=FIRST(F)-EPSILON U FIRST(T')
>
> ={(,a,b,*} U {(,a,b,*,EPSILON}
>
> ={(,a,b,*,EPSILON}
>
> FIRST(T')=FIRST(T)-EPSILON U EPSILON
>
> = FIRST(T')=FIRST(F)-EPSILON U FIRST(T')  U EPSILON
>
> ={(,a,b,*,EPSILON} /* FIRST(T') is cancel out */
>
> ={(,a,b,*} U FIRST(T') U EPSILON
>
> FIRST(F)=FIRST(P)-EPSILON U FIRST (F') U FIRST(*F') U EPSILON
>
> ={(,a,b} U EPSILON U * U EPSILON
> ={(,a,b,*,EPSILON}
>
> FIRST(F')={EPSILON}
>
> FIRST(P)=FIRST((E))-EPSILON U a U b U EPSILON
>
> ={(,a,b,EPSILON}

Comment: If you have any doubt or if you get confused from any of my above steps please feel free to ask any question.